# activity gets disappear when i click minimize/back button in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

In my app I have an activity as shown in image below  [![enter image description here][1]][1]

If I click the button "Add Patient" it will redirect to another activity. As shown in image below

If I click the home button in "NewPatient" activity it shows "My Patients" activity and "NewPatient" activity disappears.Can you please suggest how to retain "NewPatient" activity when home button is pressed when app is in "NewPatient" activity.

Manifest im using :

```
<activity
 android:name=".activity.patient.PatientsActivity"
 android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"/>

<activity
 android:name=".activity.patient.PatientFormActivity"
 android:parentActivityName=".activity.patient.PatientsActivity" />
```

Comment: hey share you code which start NewPatient Activity, are you using Flag with intent or which lauch mode are you using in manifest for NewPatient Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first solution. Launch mode based.**

You can move "My Patients" activity in front of "New Patient" activity.

1. set android:launchMode="singleTask" to "My Patients" at manifest
2. Override [`onBackPressed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) method of "New Patient" activity, and start "My Patients" from it, without calling super.

You can read more about launch modes [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

**The second solution. Bundle based**

1. Start "New Patient" activity for result from "My Patients" activity.
2. Override [`onBackPressed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) method of "New Patient" activity, and save your data to intent, as you save it to Bundle in [`onSaveInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).
3. Provide saved data to "My Patients" activity via calling [`setResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)), before calling `super.onBackPressed()`
4. Handle saved data inside [`onActivityResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) of "My Patients" activity
5. Start new instance of "New Patient" activity from "My Patients" activity with saved data.

The second one is more appropriate and less painful.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Intent for going to HomeActivity;

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) // Press Back Icon
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(NewPatient.this,HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Im asking about when i am in "New Patient" activity, when i click home navigation. After restoring its showing MyPatient Activity

Answer (score 1):

Where is your code ?
however you can use this line in your code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        //do somethings you want
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to do any extra operation for this issue. You have made a mistake somewhere else either in passing intent or any manifest. Use below example if you found any useful stuff:

From my MainActivity.java on textview click listener I started another activity:

```
findViewById(R.id.text).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),Activity2.class));
            }
        });
```

Manifest for these activities is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ccc.stackoverflow">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It works as you want to achieve. Activity2 remains open when we come back to app.Hope it helps you.